# Dart - null aware operator, why ! is needed?

Tags: flutter, dart

We have:

```
final Widget? body;
```

And later in code:

```
final content = Column(
  children: [
    ...items,
    if (body != null) body!
  ],
);
```

Why I have to add `!` sign, after body?

Without `!` I receive:

> The element type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.

In pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation sign after variable or function means converting of nullable variable or function to non-nullable value. Because as you may know widget cannot be null.

```dart
const insets = EdgeInsets.all(10.0);
Widget? widget1 = insets;
Widget widget2 = insets;
assert(widget1! == widget2);
```

Comment: It's obvious. Take a closer look, in the code, I ask if the body is null - `if (body != null) body!`. For me, this should be enough: `if (body != null) body`, because I have already asked if body is null

Comment: No, not enough. Because variable is *nullable* (Widget?) but you need Widget. So it is similar to type casting. And the compiler also warn you. In c# also `int var = (int)Nullable<int>(1);`